# Multiple Object creation using new operant

Tags: c++

I have a template class and i want to create multiple objects of that class using the new operator but i cant seem to make it work.
This is how i am trying to create the objects

```
Penalty<GraphType, AltGraph> *penalty = new  Penalty<GraphType, AltGraph>( G, AG, algTimestamp, maxNumDecisionEdges + offset)[5];
```

And the error i get is

```
penalty.cpp:343:130: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘[’ token
     Penalty<GraphType, AltGraph> *penalty = new  Penalty<GraphType, AltGraph>( G, AG, algTimestamp, maxNumDecisionEdges + offset)[5];
```

Can u please help on how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#arrays-call-default-ctor

Comment: Just use `std::vector<Penalty<GraphType, AltGraph>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the constructor once for the 5 objects of the array.

One solution could be creating an array of pointers then call new for each item in a loop:

```
Penalty<GraphType, AltGraph> **penalty = new Penalty<GraphType, AltGraph>*[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    penalty[i] = new Penalty<GraphType, AltGraph>( G, AG, algTimestamp, maxNumDecisionEdges + offset);
```